# Converting lightInject to .netcore DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, light-inject

I am converting some lightInject code to .netcore DI

In .netcore DI, we have AddSingleton and AddTransient functions for registering the service.
In the lightInject, I have RegisterMethod. So I just want to know whether the Register methods registers only singleton instance or multiple when ever we call.

Comment: Well wouldn't it be easier to start with the [docs](https://www.lightinject.net/#lifetime)? It says there *The default behavior in LightInject is to treat all objects as **transients** unless otherwise specified.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on [documentation](https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/wiki/Getting-started#lifetime) The default behavior in LightInject is to treat all objects as transients unless otherwise specified. So in .Net Core, you would need to register your services as **transient**.

A little bit about lifetimes:

**Transient**
Transient lifetime services (AddTransient) are created each time they're requested from the service container. This lifetime works best for lightweight, stateless services.

**Scoped**
Scoped lifetime services (AddScoped) are created once per client request (connection).

**Singleton**
Singleton lifetime services (AddSingleton) are created the first time they're requested (or when Startup.ConfigureServices is run and an instance is specified with the service registration). Every subsequent request uses the same instance.

Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to .Net Core dependency injection documentation.