# Convert LightInject code to Dotnetcore DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have to create some object with on demand control to flush it.

I have the code in LightInject

```
    public Lifetime()
    {
        lifetimes = new List<Flushable>();
    }

    public Lifetime Create()
    {
        var lifetime = new Flushable();
        lifetimes.Add(lifetime);
        return lifetime;
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        foreach (var lifetime in lifetimes)
        {
            lifetime.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and in DI code

```
var life = new Lifetime();
container.RegisterInstance<ILifetime>(life);
container.Register<SomeCache>(life.Create());
```

I want to move the above code to .net core DI

Is it possible with .netcore Di

Comment: You already asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57426841/converting-lightinject-to-netcore-di) with the same title. Try making the titles of your questions more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible!

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddSingleton<ILifetime, Lifetime>();
services.AddSingleton<SomeCache>(sp => {
   var lifetime = sp.GetRequiredService<ILifetime>();
   return lifetime.Create();
});  // or what ever scope u need

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var cache = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeCache>();
```

You might want to adjust the scope of `SomeCache`. With MS-DI Container you can choose between `Singleton`, `Transient` or `Scoped`. You can find an overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#extension-methods).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It will not work as I expected. Because the SomeCache doesn't accept any parameters in its constructor.

Comment: I've misread that. `SomeCache` implements `ILifetime`? Please provide the code of `SomeCache` so I can update the answer accordingly.